# updated_at column changed during insertion

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I have used "save(null, {method: 'insert'})" to add new record to a table. I don't want "updated_at" to be set during the insertion. I want update_at to remain blank until I do an update.

What is wrong ?

Product.forge({

```
    kind : 'data',
    comment : 'comment',

})
.save(null, {method: 'insert'})
```

=======================

bookshelf.Model.extend({

```
tableName : 'products',

hasTimestamps : true})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. This is the expected and designed behavior.

From the [documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-timestamp):

> ...if the model isNew or if {method: 'insert'} is provided as an option and set the created_at and updated_at attributes to the current date if it is being inserted, and just the updated_at attribute if it's being updated.

So the `updated_at` column is **always** updated both for updates AND inserts.